# Hibernate Persistent Object State. What are the possible ways a object can move to persistent state

Tags: java, hibernate, persistent

If i create a new object `obj` and persist it to db using `session.save(obj)`. Then object `obj`will move from transient state to persistent state. So the point here is... object `obj` is now in persistent state because of `session.save(obj)` call.

**What are all the other scenarios under which any object can come/move in to persistent state.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for being too broad. Why don't you start learning by reading the documentation so you end up with a better overall understanding of Hibernate?

Comment: and no it is NOT the JPA API either. Tag removed